# Identifier expected error on floating point number declaration

Tags: java

I'm getting `Identifier expected` compilation error on the following line:

```
double saludD = sueldoInt * (saludInt * 0,01);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `0,01` to `0.01`? What is `sueldoInt`?

Comment: Ohhh I feel dumb now, many thanks my friend.

Comment: @Lazaro please accept an answer which helped you solve your problem

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Which should be ParkerHalo's answer (just to mention it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java floating point numbers are dispayed with a `.`, not with a `,`. You'll have to write:

```
double saludD = sueldoInt * (saludInt * 0.01);
```

Comment: It's not _really_ the fact that it's a `float`, but the fact that Java is not European. In Europe, decimal places are separated by commas.

Comment: @Arc676 that's true (and i know, i'm from europe) But in java you must seperate decimal places by `.`

Comment: @Arc676 not _everywhere_ in Europe; England uses the dot

Comment: @fge Right. Just Italy, France, and some other places. Don't know all of them off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
double saludD = sueldoInt * (saludInt * 0,01);
```

as

```
double saludD = sueldoInt * (saludInt * 0.01);
```

If you try to compile the first one you will get,

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token ",", * expected
```

**Note:** 
Make sure that variables `sueldoInt` & `saludInt` are declared properly.